# Blender cube bevel all messed up when addig more than one cut

Tags: bevel

Desired outcome:
I want to do a cube with 4 square but smooth holes in it for 3d printer (so no edges are sharp)
Simple operations:
0. start new file with cube in center

1. add bevel modifier (picture1)
   [image]
2. I am cutting a cube bool hole with BoxCutter here, but I tried with normal bool before (picture2)
   Main cube becomes sharp again, looses most of bevel (picture2)
   [image]
3. I am cutting 3 more holes, the bottom of 3 holes becomes sharp, instead of having bevel (picture3)
   [image]
   What is the proper way to do this, so bottoms, tops and corners of square holes have bevel and so that main cube has bevel?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any of the _Boolean_ modifier settings. Maybe you should upload your file: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there. I cannot reproduce this behaviour. For the disappearing bevel I would suspect that _Clamp Overlap_ is enabled in the _Bevel_ modifier (it's the default setting) and since the cuts in the corner would only allow a very small bevel this could be the reason. Though it doesn't explain why the holes are beveled partially. But as I said, eventually it depends on the _Boolean_ modifier settings which I cannot see. Is the scale applied?

Comment: Oh, but do I see it correctly that the cutters have _Bevel_ modifiers as well? But even then I can't exactly reproduce this behaviour...

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann link for (BoxCutter addon,where I added 4 cube cuts and used Bevel, Quadrubevel and ctrl F to flip it on these holes, then I tried applying bevel to the big cube)
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WoLqP4Z8" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WoLqP4Z8/)

Here I am trying to do the same thing, but I just used standard Blender boolean modifiers:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2naASVDY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2naASVDY/)
and in this case it won't apply the bevel at all.

The goal here is to soften every sharp edge.

Comment: The second link is a file for your other question with the spherical object. For the first file (by the way, Box Cutter uses standard _Boolean_ modifiers as well, it just conveniently adjusts some settings automatically for you) it is as I said in my first comment, the _Boolean_ modifier which should bevel the main cube is set to _Clamp Overlamp_, and since the cut-outs create some edges close to the corners the bevel just gets clamped at a very small size - it's not like the cube is not beveled at all.

Answer (score 0):

For the following screenshots I've enabled *Wireframe* in the viewport's *Overlays* so that you can see what is going on.

First of all, if I disable all the *Boolean* modifiers so you can see how you have set your *Bevel* modifier. The *Amount* is 0.1 m, the *Angle* above which edges should be beveled is 30° and *Clamp Overlap* is enabled:

[image: bevel settings]

Now I enable the *Boolean* modifiers again. As you can see in the wireframe, each of the cut-out holes have connecting edges to the corners. The reason is that faces cannot have unconnected holes, they need two connections to other vertices of surrounding faces. In this case they use the corners since there are already vertices to connect to without the need to subdivide the existing outer edges.

[image: boolean result]

As you also can see in the above screenshot, the already beveled edges of the holes get beveled again - because the angles are 45°, and every angle above 30° gets beveled.

With the *Clamp Overlap* enabled this now reduces the bevel to a very small amount, since the corners can only be beveled a very tiny bit without overlapping due to the connecting edges of the holes. On a side note, the clamping does not allow individual edges to be beveled as much as possible, all edge bevels are limited to the minimum amount possible.

In order to make the *Bevel* modifier work, you have to keep in mind that holes need supporting edges. The modifier creates them automatically very arbitrary and slight changes in the cutter objects' positions can change the connections as well. However, on geometry like this they will connect to the corners which is problematic for beveling.

So before cutting holes it is best to intentionally place supporting edges where they are less damaging to your bevels, for example with the *Loop Cut* tool <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> you can cut two edges across the cube going more or less through the center of where the holes should be, like this for example (or maybe even two more in the other direction as well):

[image: create supporting edges]

If you now enable the *Boolean* modifiers again, you can see the holes do not connect to the corners anymore. But still the bevel amount is not as much as in the first image without the holes:

[image: bevel angle too low]

The reason for this is simple. The clamping is still active, and now the edges of the holes are beveled to the maximum amount before they overlap - and that's limiting the outer bevel on the main cube. The edge angles on the holes are 45°, so if you set the *Angle* in the *Bevel* modifier to something like 50° or 60°, the cube edges with 90° angles will still be beveled, but the ones on the boundaries of the holes not:

[image: bevel angle increased]